# Why does Haskell precedence have only 10 levels? Is the figure of 10 enough?

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence

I want to know why Haskell designers agreed to allow only 10 levels of precedence? Has anybody found it insufficient ?

Answer (score 22):

To the best of my knowledge, it's completely arbitrary. All the documentation I'm aware of simply states it as a point of fact, with no elaboration or justification.

But if you think about it, why would anything else be better? Okay, let's say 10 isn't enough. You've got `(.)` which has the highest fixity and you want something else that binds a bit tighter. You add an extra level, so your new maximum is 10 (even though most fixities only go to 9).

Now you have 11 levels of precedence. (*That's ridiculous. It's not even funny.*) How is this any less arbitrary than 10? What's to stop you from adding more? What if you want new levels between existing ones? Sure, you can keep adding more, until eventually you find yourself writing `infix↑ (ω + 2i)` and wondering where your life went wrong.

The thing is, operator precedence is inherently a pretty arbitrary thing. There are a few conventions--multiplicative things binding tighter than additive ones, logical operators having lower precedence than boolean-valued functions like `(==)`--but those are somewhat limited, and usually don't cover more than a few levels. Otherwise, the only way to remember operator precedences is to... well, remember them, as in simply memorize each one. Not only is this a chore, it can make code opaque to others who may not have everything memorized as well. Human working memory is a very limited resource, so the fewer picky details that need to be recalled while coding, the better.

Most uses of operators in Haskell where precedence matters fall into one of several rough groups:

- Pseudosyntactic operators like the common use of `($)`, which typically need extremely high or low precedence to avoid conflicting with other operators.
- Expressions using standard operators, or variations thereof, where a handful of standard precedence levels exist and new operators should generally share the same level as whatever they're based on.
- Specialized operator sets, such as for an EDSL, whose symbols and precedence levels are typically chosen to reflect the nature of the EDSL and are unlikely to coexist with other sets of operators.

All of those manage just fine with only a few precedence levels. More importantly, they're characterized by either being effectively independent of other operators or only used together with a very limited set of other operators. Start adding in more operators and mixing them together in single expressions and pretty soon people will start using explicit parentheses anyway because they can't remember what binds more tightly than what. Speaking for myself, I'm already prone to explicit parenthesization when mixing EDSL-style operators (say, `Arrow` combinators) with logical operators because I can't usually recall the exact precedence levels each one has.

So, having established that: **1)** lots of extra precedence levels wouldn't be that useful because it's too much to keep track of, and **2)** any limit we pick is going to be equally arbitrary... why 10? I'm going to guess "because then fixity values are only single digits".

Comment: @mu is too short: Ah, that would be "most fixities only go to 9". :) Most amps go to 10, though, since rock musicians tend to count from 1, not 0. But the range is equivalent. (Actually, a lot of the phrasing in that paragraph was imitating the lines from Spinal Tap, but that's more subtle)

Comment: I guess when one counts the levels one needs for numbers (additive, multiplicative, exponential), relational operators and logical operators (&&, ||) one already has six levels (maybe seven, if you want `a < b == b < c`). Plus then you want some that bind tighter or not, so it is hard to imagine how one could do with less than 10.

Comment: "Human working memory is a very limited resource, so the fewer picky details that need to be recalled while coding, the better.", very nice.

Answer (score 8):

The number of levels is arbitrary, and as I recall the decision was that lots of levels just makes it hard to remember how the operators interact.  For instance Prolog allows 1000 levels, but I've never found that to be much better than Haskell.

Extending Haskell precedences levels you could imagine changing to a rational number, that way you can always fit an operator between two existing operator.  But a better choice would probably be to switch to the precedences being a partial order.  So given two operators they can be related and then handled accordingly, or unrelated which would force parenthesis.

Comment: Honestly the partial order seems closer to how I actually think about it. Though I'm not sure how that would handle operators like `($)`, where you just want it to be "lower than most/all other operators". Simply having unique greatest/least precedences seems rather inflexible.

Comment: @camccann I've not seen a satisfactory solution to this yet.  So we are stuck with what we have, which is still better than most languages.

Comment: Aww, I was hoping you'd figured that part out, too. :] Oh well. The way it is now does seem pretty close to a local maximum for the power/complexity ratio.